# Including a period in apache modrewrite rule causes errors

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have this and it works perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ view.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

I also want it to match string with periods in them, so I change it to

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/?$ view.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

But it no longer works and the value being passed to $1 is "view.php"!

Comment: This is in `.htaccess` I assume?

Answer (score 0):

This works but I don't know why

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ view.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This can result in a different response to the rule as posted in your question. I've outlined the differences in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75877433/369434).

Answer (score 0):

> But it no longer works and the value being passed to `$1` is "view.php"!

Because the regex `^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/?$` (including a dot) also matches the rewritten URL `view.php`. In a *directory* context (`.htaccess` files and `<Directory>` containers) the rewriting process does not stop at the first pass through the mod_rewrite directives (by default). It repeats/loops until the URL passes through unchanged, and this is what you are seeing here.

You've not stated the URL you are requesting, but if you make a request for `/example.foo` then what happens is:

1. `/example.foo` rewritten to `view.php?id=example.foo`
2. No `L` or `END` flag so processing continues through the file.
3. Rewriting process starts over with the URL `/view.php?id=example.foo`
4. `/view.php?id=example.foo` rewritten to `view.php?id=view.php` (`id=example.foo` is overwritten since the `QSA` flag is not used)
5. No `L` or `END` flag so processing continues through the file.
6. Rewriting process starts over with the URL `/view.php?id=view.php`.
7. `/view.php?id=view.php` rewritten to `view.php?id=view.php`.
8. URL passes through unchanged. Rewriting process ends.

> This works but I don't know why
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ view.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

This "works" because the first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) is only successful when the request does *not* map to a physical file. `view.php` is a physical file so the condition fails (no further rewriting occurs after point #3 above).

However, this is slightly different to your original directive and could result in a different result since in your original directive you are allowing for an optional trailing slash, but excluding this from the captured subpattern. For example, a request for `/example/` would get rewritten to `view.php?id=example` by your original rule, but to `view.php?id=example/` (with a trailing slash on the `id` URL parameter) by this second rule. You are also matching "anything" in this second rule, so it would rewrite `/foo/bar/baz`, which would not have been rewritten by your original rule. You should be using the same regex (`RewriteRule` *pattern*).

Also, due to the use of the `QSA` flag, if you were to request `/example?id=another` it would rewrite the request to `view.php?id=example&id=another` and your PHP script would likely see `id=another`, not `id=example` (if you are using the `$_GET` superglobal in PHP).

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/?$ view.php?id=$1 [NC]
> ```

You shouldn't really allow an optional trailing slash on the rewrite since it potentially opens you up to duplicate content since both `/example` and `/example/` (two different URLs) are both rewritten to the same `view.php?id=example`. Only one of these URLs should be canonical. If you do need to allow requests to both then you should canonicalise the URL with an external redirect to either remove or append the trailing slash.

You are also missing the `L` (or `END`) flag. The `NC` is not necessary since your regex already matches both `a-z` and `A-Z` (alternatively, remove `A-Z` from the regex). You need to backslash-escape literal dots when used inside a regex character class.

To resolve the issue on Apache 2.4 you could simply use the `END` flag, which stops all processing, preventing additional loops by the rewrite engine. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9.]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [NC,END]
```

Alternatively, on Apache 2.2 you can check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var that is empty on the initial request and set to the HTTP status code after the first successful rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9.]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is more efficient than checking that the request does not map to a file, unless that is also a requirement.